# Date display bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I found a bug, viewing my questions sorted by views. Can you see it?

[image]

If you're having trouble, I'll highlight it for you:

[image]

May 26th of ***what year???*** This is important!

Comment: When there's no year shown, I must assume that it means this year. That question is from the future.

Comment: '13, I imagi-- wait...

Comment: There appears to be some kind of cutoff in the middle of May of last year where the year starts getting added. [Example](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/28/famous-question?userid=1719) *stealth brag*.

Comment: @StrixVaria [Eh.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8097403#8097403)

Comment: lol @ stealth brag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no year is shown it means the latest year it can possibly be.

You can hover over the date label to see the UTC timestamp - this will show you the full date and time in [ISO 8061](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format

---

Update:

Digging deeper, we have a cutoff of 330 days - if the date is under 330 days ago, the year will not be shown.

Comment: That seems weird. Why is March shown with '12 in the screenshots then? And on MSO posts went to "Nov 25 '12" or whatever basically as soon as we hit 2013 in UTC.

Comment: @Anna - didn't notice that. Will investigate once I am back in the office.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Found the reason... answer updated.

Comment: @Oded Why 330 days? I'd love to know the origin of that value...

Comment: @fredley - Good question. It is just shy of 11 months, so I guess that's why. I doubt an answer except it being arbitrary would surface.